# Calculate orbital speed of object around earth (SpaceX data)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites, data

I am just reading [SpaceX rocket data satisfies elementary Hohmann transfer formula](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6552/ab5f4c/pdf), a paper of how to use SpaceX telemetry data in educational physics.

In particular the paper contains the following table of telemetry data:

[image]

As a first test, I tried to calculate $v_1$ from $h_1$. Assuming a circular orbit the centripetal force is by the gravitational force, i.e.

$$
\frac{mv^2}{r} = \gamma \cdot \frac{mM}{r^2}
$$
i.e.
$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r}}
$$

Letting $v = v_1$ and $r = r_E + h_1$ with earth radius $r_E$ in this case, I get

$$
v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r_E + h_1}}
$$

Where $M$ denotes the mass of the earth and $r_E$ the .

Plugging in the data for example for the first flight (F9-22), I get:

$$
v_1 = 27831.11 \, \mathrm{\frac{km}{h}}
$$

where I used
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma &= 6.67408\cdot 10^{-11} \,\mathrm{\frac{Nm^2}{kg^2}} \\
r_E &= 6378100.0 \, \mathrm{m}\\
M_E &= 5.972167867791379\cdot 10^{24} \, \mathrm{kg}\\
\end{align}
$$ (from python constants library).

I.e. I was not able to reproduce the number in the table. Same with the other data. Take for example the flight with the smallest PCT error (F9-49):

Then I get: $v_1 = 27919.16 \, \mathrm{\frac{km}{h}}$.

So what did I do wrong? Where does the discrepancy come from?

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  Velocities in the table do not match the heights if we assume circular orbits.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the paper and I can't say anything more.